# Proving the following fact about the matrix exponential.

Tags: matrices

Assume the formula $\det(e^A)=e^{\operatorname{tr}(A)}$ for all matrices $A \in \mathbb{C}_{n\times n}$.

Show why this implies that the exponential always yields a regular matrix.

Comment: And what is a regular matrix?

Comment: Since $\exp(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^*$, we have $\mbox{det}(e^A)=e^{\mbox{Tr}A}\neq 0$. So $e^A$ is invertible.

Comment: A regular nxn matrix. I think.

Comment: It is a rare usage (as claimed by wiki), but regular means invertible here.

Comment: @Fraiser please make sure that I edited your post in a way that represents your original intent...

Comment: The word 'regular' is regularly overused.

Comment: it is e to the power of tr(A)

Comment: Do you know that a square matrix is invertible (regular) if and only if its determinant is nonzero?

Comment: so how do you think i should use that to answer th question?

Comment: @Fraiser: You have to do some work. All you need is in the comments above. First, know what you mean by regular. Second, connect regular with the determinant value, and third, use facts about the exponential to conclude something about the determinant in question.

Comment: Or, read Ittay's answer...

Comment: thank you copper hat for your input

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just combine the following two facts:

1) $e^t\ne 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb C$

2) An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is regular (meaning invertible) if, and only if, $\det(A)\ne 0$.